# Das has become den and it's not dative plural

Tags: grammatical-case

I used DeepL to translate two sentences from English to German:

i) I will keep the gum for myself.
2) I will keep the gum myself.

It came up with:

1. Ich werde den Kaugummi für mich behalten.
2. Ich werde das Kaugummi selbst behalten.

I cannot figure out why in the first sentence "das Kaugummi" becomes "den Kaugummi". It is not the dative for "das" and I can't think of any circumstances in which this would happen. Can anyone help?

Comment: Like all machine learning solutions, DeepL creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) the DeepL output aspect is not concerning language but the results of a certain software processing it. b) What remains is a simple gender question - off topic either, since it can be answered using a dictionary. c) The suggested dative is not correct in any application of *behalten* I can imagine.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct because "Kaugummi" has ambiguous grammatical gender: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaugummi)

Comment: Where I come from, _das Gummi_ is pretty much reserved for condomes.

Comment: @phipsgabler: We are both from Graz (I was born there, but now live somewhere else), but I still always say *der Gummi,* also for condomes. I am 55 years old now. I observed for many years, that younger people adopt the language they hear in TV and read in magazines (which is German German) much more than my generation. Todays young people (20 or younger) who live in Vienna hardly can understand dialect lyrics from austropop songs from the 1970ies and 1980ies. And so it's not a big surprise for me to read, that someone who lives where I was born says *das Gummi.*

Comment: Oh, really? A very plausible theory, given my age. Admittedly, I'm only have unstructured L2 acquisition of "real" Austrian dialects. My "bürgerliches Grazerisch" of younger generation is indeed already pretty far from anything proper Styrian.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast that makes at least 3 of us :-). I can confirm your observations.

Comment: @phipsgabler: urban dialects (dialects spoken in bigger cities) are always different from the dialects spoken in rural areas near those cities, because immigrants (not only from foreign countries, but also from other parts of the same country) want to live in the cities, not in rural areas. Just think of the many thousands of students who live in such cities, coming from anywhere in the world. This is the reason why urban dialects change faster and are much closer to standard language than dialects form rural regions.

Answer (score 4):

The noun [*Kaugummi*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaugummi) has two grammatical genders: masculine (*der* Kaugummi) and neuter (*das* Kaugummi). The masculine gender is more common, and some dictionaries, such as the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kaugummi), only list that one.

In any case, the gender that you assign to it determines how the casus forms look like. For instance, the accusative forms that appear in your example sentences are:

> - Ich werde *den Kaugummi* für mich behalten. (masculine)
> - Ich werde *das Kaugummi* für mich behalten. (neuter)

Comment: Do you have a source for »way more common«? I could only find http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Gummi and if I multiply the population of the regions and the relative frequency of occurrence of the two genders, I find that roughly 2/3 of Germany say »das Gummi«. The result doesn't change much if you consider another 9m Austrians who say »der Gummi«.

Comment: @Raketenolli *Kaugummi* does not need to follow *Gummi*. Given that DWDS only mentions the masculine variant and Duden lists it as primary, the assertion in question seems warranted.

Comment: @Raketenolli This may apply to *Gummi*, but not necessarily to *Kaugummi*. Whatever, duden.de writes *"der, auch das Kaugummi"* and the DWDS does not even mention the neuter form. Also Pfeifer writes *"Kaugummi **m.** (20er Jahre 20. Jh.), nach amerik.-engl. chewing gum (1864)."* These are no proofs but hints. But to tone it down a bit, I will delete in the answer the emphasizing word *way*.

Comment: I agree with »more common« as it is given as the dominant or only gender in all dictionaries we've looked at. To me personally *Kaugummi* follows from *Gummi* just like *Radiergummi* does. Where I grew up (southern Niedersachsen) all of them were *das ...gummi*.

Comment: I was raised in the GDR. For me *das Gummi* is simply short for *das Gummiband*, like those small red elastic bands or the famous *Schlüpfergummis*, or a synonyme for *Kondom*. *Gummi*-things made of a rubber-like mass, including *Radiergummi* and *Kaugummi*, are masculine for me.